# Error: Protocol:191.168.XXX.XXX: not supported

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code:

```
http.get('191.168.XXX.XXX:219/query', function (res) {
    ...
});
```

The IP is pointed to another machine running node.js too, and redirect to the real file to be downloaded (the check of res.headers.location come after this line). Problem is, even when I can access this IP:port with any browser, node.js just throw a exception:

```
http.js:1840
    throw new Error('Protocol:' + options.protocol + ' not supported.');
          ^
Error: Protocol 191.168.XXX.XXX: not supported.
    at Object.exports.request (http.js:1840:11)
    at Object.exports.get (http.js:1840:11)
    at get_link (/home/pi/app.js:XXX:XX)
    at init (/home/pi/app.js:XXX:XX)
    at Object.cb [as oncomplete] (fs.js:168.19)
```

So it seems http.get don t like my address, knowing that I need to call another.

I tried with:

```
file_url = {
hostname : 191.168.XXX.XXX,
port : 219,
path : 'query'
};
```

I instead get ECONNREFUSED...

EDIT:

So, after some trial and error with making the url, I ve come to do this:

```
var link = {
        protocol: 'http:',
        hostname: '191.168.XXX.XXX',
        port: 219,
        path: '/?query'
    };
http.get(link, function (res) {
    console.log(res.statusCode + ' ' + res.headers.location);
    ...
});
```

Server side, the code is:

```
function web (req, res) {
    console.log('Request!');
    var page = url.parse(req.url).pathname,
        query = url.parse(req.url).query;
    console.log(query + ' asked for smil');
    if(page === '/' && smil[query]) {
        log('ACCEPT', 'Redirecting to ' + smil[query]);
        res.writeHead(302,
            {Location: smil[query]}
        );
        res.end();
    } else { //AUTRE
        console.log('Refusing connection');
        res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.end();      
    }
}
```

If I call 191.168.XXX.XXX from my browser, I get redirected or refused correctly if I have valid arguments. But from my client code, I still get ECONNREFUSED before http.get call back.

Comment: In that last sample you specify that the server runs on port 219, which would be a *very* unusual port for a webserver.  Are you sure that there's a webserver listening on that port on the target computer?

Comment: Try `http.get('http://191.168.XXX.XXX:219/query', function (res) {` because http.js seems to expect that you define the URL you are requesting properly, ie including the protocol.

Comment: Is node.js expecting a protocol in the URL?  `http.get('http://191...`

Comment: are you meaning to use a local network address 192.168.x.x?

Comment: @fvu: Yes there is one, I have another node.js server on that port at the pointed adress. I ll try when I l get back to that project : )

Comment: @DrakaSAN your example uses address `191.168.XXX.XXX` but you state that you want a private address, ie `192.168.XXX.XXX`...  That's one issue, the missing `http://` is probably the second issue.

Comment: @DrakaSAN you are still using 191 as your first address byte, but I *most strongly* suspect your address starts with 192 - addresses starting with 191 are public addresses.  So, now you are sending a request to some random machine somewhere on the internet.  Check and make 100% sure that you are using the correct address.

Comment: @fvu: I don t know how to express my shame right now.

Comment: @DrakaSAN These things happen, the only important question here is whether your problem got solved - can you confirm that it's working now?  If so, it's maybe better to delete this question.

Comment: It work now, but since some have post has answer, I can t simply delete the question.

Comment: @fvu: Since it seems it will take a long time for mods to close the question, could you write your comment as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @DrakaSAN interestingly, after hanging around for a month in limbo this question was closed within 12 hours after I added my answer ...  SO's ways are mysterious sometimes.

Comment: @fvu: Just that answering got it back to the "hot" page, catch the attention for some people, who voted to close. WWe weren t that far of the close vote either way, just sad for the rep point you loose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using 191 as your first address byte, but I most strongly suspect your address starts with 192 - addresses starting with 191 are public addresses, see [RFC-1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) for an overview of address ranges reserved for private networks.

So, now you are sending a request to some random machine somewhere on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

According to Node's [HTTP docs](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback), the `get` method is just like the `request` method, which uses Node's [`url.parse`](http://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstr_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost) to parse URLs. While `url.parse` *can* handle scheme-less URLs, the leading colon in your port component (`:219`) causes `parse` to think your URL *does* have a scheme (here, the initial `192.168.XXX.XXX`), which is obviously not a supported scheme.

The solution here is to explicitly specify a scheme, e.g., `http://192.168.XXX.XXX/query`.